# Fill array only once in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray

I am filling array in view did load method but the problem is that each time view is loaded it adds again and again same content i want that if first time view is loaded then it should add contents in array not in the second time repeatedly.
Here is my code:

```
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {

            Coffee*obj=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog(@"This is working %d",i);

            [appDelegate.arrayOne addObject:obj];   
    }


    for (int a=5;a<8;a++) {


        Coffee*obj=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:a];


        [appDelegate.arrayTwo addObject:obj];   
    }
```

two array i am filling from another array but it repeats values if we move from one view to another and again come back

Comment: shall the value be populated once in a app session or saved for the next runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check that here it have any value then remove that all data from array like bellow..

```
   if ([appDelegate.arrayOne count]>0) {
         [appDelegate.arrayOne removeAllObjects];
   }

   if ([appDelegate.arrayTwo count]>0) {
         [appDelegate.arrayTwo removeAllObjects];
   }

   for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {

            Coffee*obj=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog(@"This is working %d",i);

            [appDelegate.arrayOne addObject:obj];   
    }


    for (int a=5;a<8;a++) {


        Coffee*obj=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:a];


        [appDelegate.arrayTwo addObject:obj];   
    }
```

and the add in that array..

Comment: can you please edit in my code

Comment: Why remove all objects if they are the same that would be added later? Skip the adding mechanics if these arrays do have values. That results in the same values being in the array but at lower resource consume because they are not added repeatedly.

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone i edit my answer whole your whole code... :) wel-come  plzz accept answer and upvote me if its useful to you...

Comment: @TRD if every time or after some time here we got different data at that time this concept is useful so i do that...

Comment: @ParashJoshi one another general question that my audio file is play perfectly on simulator but it is not playing on device what would be the issue

Comment: @ParasJoshi If this data really does change since when it was added then I would prefer to keep the changes instead of revising them to some default values. But may be this case is just more a philosophical topic and not what the starter intended. I just wanted to point out that there is a possibility to "ensmart" that piece :)

Comment: if you use this type of code then i should work perfactly.. NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"adriantnt_release_click" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio play];

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone also check setting of your device also check out volume of device.. :)

Comment: @TRD yes dude you are right and some of data i use with this point like Country Array or something like that which not changed in future at that time i use that concept.. :) thanx friend

Comment: @ParasJoshi here is the link i have posted code please help me out in this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033723/audio-file-not-working-on-device-but-it-is-working-on-simulator

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using `NSMutableArray` use `removeAllObjects` method avilable for Array before adding objects to it. [Checkout Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)